# android- How to make a listview like this

Tags: android, android-listview

this is a listview that I want to make ,i want to use it for a navigation drawer [image]

as you can see, it separate the categories , I can have several different categories .

How can I make something like this ? is it possible to do it in one listview ?

thanks

Comment: You need an ExpandableListView. Look here, good Example: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: Deplicated Please check this http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **Section ListView** if all the sub categories is always `Visible`. or else you can go for `ExpandibleListView`.

By using it you can show list item in `Categories`.

Try Open **source project available in Github**.. [Section ListView](https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview) and [Example2](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/simple-section-adapter)

There is an easy sample for Section ListView [Here](http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-section-listview.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in many ways. One of them is tweaking your `getView()` method.

- First you have to define two different layouts for category header
  and category items.
- Create a listview layout and a CustomAdapter.
- The `position` parameter in the `getView()` method in the adapter is the
  index in the list, it's up to you to determine the indexes and
  add related layout.
- Call your adapter and set it in your activity.

In `getView()`, you can follow the following procedure

```
if(position==0 || position==3 || position==7){
    //Add the header
}else{
    //Add the sub-items
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Expandable ListView refer these tutorials:

[Tutorial 1](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129)

[Tutorial 2](http://www.coderzheaven.com/expandable-listview-android-simpleexpandablelistadapter-simple-example/)

My personal favourite [Link](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/)